# How to make Task and give him Permation in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, task

I have team web site & I want to make task in this application the team leader assign task & Every Employee see his task hoe can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the team leader full control in the list
2. Have team leader create task
3. Click into newly created task
4. Click Edit Permissions on toolbar at top of task display
5. Grant permissions to all employees (or better still, leverage SharePoint's groups).

To have this done automatically, I'd suggest creating a feature with a custom list derived from the Task List and create event handlers for the list that automatically delegate permissions appropriately.